# Paperclip: How to upload Powerpoint presentation files

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, file-upload, paperclip

How to upload powerpoint presentation files and other office related documents using rails paperclip processor.

Here is my code.
In **mime_types.rb**

```
Mime::Type.register "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document", :docx
Mime::Type.register "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation", :pptx
Mime::Type.register "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", :xlsx
```

In my model **asset.rb**

```
has_attached_file :attachment, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }, :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png"
validates_attachment_content_type :attachment, :content_type => ["application/pdf", "application/zip", "application/x-zip", "application/x-zip-compressed","application/octet-stream","image/jpg", "image/png", "image/jpeg", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"]
```

I am receiving this error
Assets attachment content type is invalid
Assets attachment is invalid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Model

```
validates_attachment_content_type :attachment, :content_type => ["application/pdf", "application/zip", "application/x-zip", "application/x-zip-compressed","application/octet-stream","application/vnd.ms-office","application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet","application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation","image/jpg", "image/png", "image/jpeg"]
```

In your mime_types.rb

```
Mime::Type.register "application/pdf", :pdf
```

```
Mime::Type.register "application/xls", :xls
Rack::Mime::MIME_TYPES.merge!({
    ".xls"     => "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet",  
    ".xlsx"     => "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet",
    ".ppt"     => "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation",
    ".pptx"     => "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation",
    ".doc"     => "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document",
    ".docx"     => "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document",
})
```

Answer (score 2):

try with this mime type for ppt,

```
Mime::Type.register "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation", :pptx
```

use below link for more reference.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee309278(v=office.12).aspx

and , also you can merge more mime type as below

```
Rack::Mime::MIME_TYPES.merge!({
  ".pptx"     => "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation",
  ".xlsx"     => "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
})
```